# Optimize MySQL query to find rank of a user for differnet tests in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the query to find the rank of a user in a given test id, and this gives me rank for just one test at a time and I have to use foreach to get the test rank of all the test.

```
SELECT * , t.UserRank
FROM (

SELECT * , (
@rownum := @rownum +1
)UserRank
FROM User_Date_Table, (

SELECT @rownum :=0
)t
WHERE my_test_id  = '$test_id'
ORDER BY test_score DESC
)t
WHERE user_id = '$my_user_id'
```

Can a query be generated which can give me user rank for all the test taken by user in single query as this will reduced the db hitting multiple times.

I have to find the all the ranks of user with Test_Type_Id = $my_test_type_id(say), joining a.id with b.my_test_id for a user with user_id = $my_user_id(say)

```
TABLE STRUCTURE

  My_Test_Table (a)

  id  |  name   |  Test_Type_Id 
  ----------------------------------------------
  1  |  name_1  |  1
  2  |  name_2  |  1    
  3  |  name_3  |  2    
  4  |  name_4  |  1    
  5  |  name_5  |  1
  6  |  name_6  |  2    
  7  |  name_7  |  1    
  8  |  name_8  |  2    
  9  |  name_9  |  1



 User_Date_Table (b)

id  | my_test_id | user_id  | test_score
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1  | 32    | 34
2  | 1  | 2     | 345
3  | 2  | 4     | 654
4  | 1  | 76    | 87
5  | 3  | 23    | 453
6  | 2  | 5     | 45
7  | 1  | 43    | 22
8  | 2  | 7     | 987
9  | 2  | 32    | 45
10  | 1     | 1     | 12
11  | 1     | 9 | 35
12  | 3     | 67    | 765
13  | 1     | 88    | 23
14  | 2     | 34    | 76
15  | 3     | 1     | 765
16  | 2     | 54    | 45
17  | 1     | 10    | 87
18  | 1     | 23    | 3
19  | 3     | 44    | 345
20 | 1  | 55    | 232
21  | 2     | 28    | 234
22  | 3     | 32    | 231
```

Comment: Could you add some simple sample data and a desired result? It's not quite clear to me what you want the output of the query to look like.

Comment: say we need to find the rank of user_id =32  in test type 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is probably to just remove the user variable for ranking and just do it using a subquery;

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 
           FROM User_Date_Table b 
           WHERE a.my_test_id = b.my_test_id
             AND a.test_score < b.test_score) userrank
FROM User_Date_Table a
WHERE user_id = '1';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/398e7c/1).

Comment: how to connect it with another table .. by selecting the type of test ..to set my_test_id

Comment: Could you add a sample result to your question for the sample data you're giving? You never mentioned that in your question, and I don't understand what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Its working all well .. just need to join the two tables ..where my_test_id will be taken form the type of test ..say for only test type 1 we need to find ..
I have to find the all the ranks of user with Test_Type_Id = $my_test_type_id(say), joining a.id with b.my_test_id for a user with user_id = $my_user_id(say)

Comment: here you are finding for all the test but i need to find for only specific type test ...

Comment: SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 
           FROM User_Date_Table b 
           WHERE a.my_test_id = b.my_test_id
             AND a.test_score < b.test_score) userrank
FROM User_Date_Table a LEFT jOIN My_Test_Table c 
ON c.id =  a.my_test_id
WHERE a.user_id = '1' AND c.Test_Type_Id = '1';

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * , t.UserRank
FROM (    
    SELECT * , @rownum :=if(@user!=user_id,0, @rownum +1),@user:=user_id UserRank
    FROM User_Date_Table , (SELECT @rownum :=0,@user :=-1) t
    ORDER BY my_test_id ,test_score DESC
    )t
WHERE user_id = '$my_user_id'
```

We introducean additional variable @user to reset @rownum on user_id change

Comment: here user id is same so we need to reset the test_id ?